# How to display JPG file from SD Card in ImageView with BitmapFactory - Android Studio

Tags: android, bitmap

I could use some help. This is my first android projects. I want to take a picture with the camera and then display it in ImageView. I can take pictures and save it in a folder on SD card (path to file is always the same), but I can't get it to display in ImageView.
(File is there, as I am using the same path for email.intent to send it over email client and it works.)

Code for displaying image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    final File imgFile = new  File("/storage/emulated/0/camera_app/cam_image.jpg");
    if(imgFile.exists()){

        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        ImageView kamera3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kamera2);
        kamera3.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
     }
```

I tried also:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/emulated/0/camera_app/cam_image.jpg");
ImageView kamera3= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kamera2);
kamera3.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: have you checked runtime permission?

Comment: paste your complete code, since you are not checking for requestCode and resultCode in above onActivityresult method.

Comment: add permission to manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Tried it again and it works ! Thank you for help!

Comment: I needed to add 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `uri` to this function

```
public static Bitmap createBitmap(String photoPath) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Then set it to `ImageView`

```
image_view.setImageBitmap(Constants.createBitmap("uri"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(prva.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(prva.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        {    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(prva.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was missing

Comment: I also add  private static final int MY_PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;